# Using python to render jinja2 templates with secrets retrieved from Hashicorp Vault

Tags: python, jinja2, hashicorp-vault

Using pure python, I'm trying to retrieve secrets stored in Hashicorp Vault to populate in Jinja2 templates. I have the role_id, secret_id, client_token and the path where the key value is stored. HOW and WHAT is the best way within the jinja2 template do I retrieve the value?

Since secret_id is considered a "password", it's probably not best practice to hardcode it on the template - so how would I be able to overcome this issue?

Comment: Retrieve it in Python code and hand it to the template as context.

Comment: @KlausD. May you please help to elaborate? Should I use hvac to interface? etc....